# ROS on ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers?

Tags: ros, microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to run ROS, or some cut-down part of it, on ARM Cortex-M processors?  There's some pretty nice chips out there, like the STM32F429ZIT6, a Cortex-M4F with up to 2MB Flash, 256k RAM and 100+ I/O lines.  These sorts of uC's also include lots of ADC, DAC, timer/counter etc hardware that seems to be less common on the faster Cortex-A SoC's but that would be pretty handy on a lot of robots.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131501/ros-on-arm-cortex-m-microcontrollers?/) by [asperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/12271/asperion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are various in-progress projects to implement the ROS communication stack in a way that has no dependencies and could work with, for example, LWIP. The most complete at this point is probably [rosc](http://wiki.ros.org/rosc).

That said, my preferred solution is to use [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial)—you run a lightweight server node on your Linux/ROS machine, which proxies topics and services from the "real" ROS network over a serial or socket connection to the microcontroller. There are several examples of rosserial client libs; unfortunately none for a Cortex at this point, but it wouldn't take much to port the Arduino example to it.

Disclosure: I'm the author of the performance- and reliability-oriented C++ rosserial_server implementation.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/12271/asperion/) on 2014-03-04**:
Thanks, that's a pretty comprehensive answer.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2017-04-18**:
Is there any news about the ROS support for ARM-based boards?

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2017-04-24**:
There are official armhf packages from OSRF for Ubuntu Xenial (ROS Kinetic). Is that what you mean?

cf. http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2017-04-24**:
Thank you for your answer! I mean if ROS has now full support and if it is possible to use all the ROS packages like `robot_localization` and `move_base`.